# Executing Oracle JDK 7u10 through an OS X App Bundle -- Where are the Logs?

Tags: java, macos

I am running Oracle JDK 7u10 (the latest developer preview). I have packaged a Java application as a .app bundle using the [Simplericity Java Packaging plugin](http://simplericity.com/2007/09/19/1190234671861.html).  When I execute my app, I get a pop-up with an exception: "Uncaught exception in Main method: 'java.lang.exceptionInInitializerError", but no stack trace. I would like to view the full stack trace to figure out what's going on.  Where does the log end up for apps launched this way?  I have tried to redirect System.err to a file, but I believe the exception is being thrown from within the Simplericity code, so it never gets to my app's main method and redirects the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard output generated by an `.app` is captured by the operating system. It should be visible using `Console.app`, or by running `syslog -C` in the Terminal.